# Git pull issue: where is the URL stored GIT goes for performing his pull requests?

Tags: git, vpn, git-extensions

Generally my GIT extensions application is working fine, but when I'm working with a VPN, I get into this problem, while trying to pull my `Module-Solution`:

```
"git" pull --rebase --progress "origin"
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.Server_URL/Git_Server/Module-Solution.git/':
Could not resolve host: git.Server_URL
Done

Press Enter or Esc to exit...
```

This is due to the fact that, while working with a VPN, `git.Server_URL` is not found.

I would like to know where `git.Server_URL` is configured and what about the `Git_Server`?
For your information: while working with `git bash` I get exactly the same error.

Comment: The configuration on where to pull (or push) for is called [a remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote). In your case the remote is called `origin`. See its details by `git remote get-url --all origin`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: is that configuration general for all GIT repositories or is this specific for every repository? ... and how can I change this value?

Comment: Remotes are configured per-repository. You can use `git remote set-url` to change which URL(s) a remote accessed. See my link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the configured URLs for your remotes with [`git remote -v show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emshowem) or get them with [`git remote get-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emget-urlem) and update them with [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem)

The configuration is stored in the per-repository configuration file `.git/config`, see [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegturl).